# Is "the" needed in the following scenario?

Tags: definite-articles

I am just going to make a scenario of which nothing has been mentioned before in my paper. The scenario is as follows:

> A biology student hears, while she is cooking in **the** kitchen, that someone on the TV says Scottish wildcat will most probably be extinct in upcoming years.

I haven't talked about kitchen before, so I shouldn't put "the" before it, but then without "the" it sounds weird.

Comment: Problem with sentence is not kitchen.  Hear should be hears, distinct should be extinct (unless you mean to say that she mishears it).  Also, where else but the kitchen would she be cooking?

Comment: @YosefBaskin Thanks. I edited the question. So you say "the" is necessary because people usually cook in kitchens ??

Comment: Sorry, 'the' is necessary for a few reasons, like cooking 'in kitchen' is right out, and cooking in 'a' kitchen forces the reader to stop (usually a bad thing) and ask "Some kitchen?  Which one?  Can't say exactly?  What's the mystery?"  Perhaps you mean she is cooking, or she is in the kitchen, or she hears indistinctly while she is cooking in the kitchen with the TV a room or two away?

Comment: I think *the* is also missing before *Scottish wildcat*, because the phrase denotes the whole species.

Comment: Phrases like "in the kitchen" or "in the bathroom" are a normal way of referring to that room in the house where the action is taking place. It doesn't matter that it hasn't been mentioned before.